# Check if coordinates create a loop

Tags: scala

I store tuples of x/y-coordinates for a walker in an array `ArrayBuffet((Int, Int))`.

Steps that represent the journey between `(0,0)` and `(2,1)` can be `((0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1))`, `((0,0), (1,1), (2,1))`, etc.

Trouble is, I need a way to test if the walker is travelling in circles.

E.g. Consider a walk from `(0,0)` to `(0,1)`, where the walker's path is `((0,0), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,0), (0,1))`. The walker will have travelled in a circle.

Method

```
def hasLoop(path: ArrayBuffer[(Int,Int)]): Boolean = {
    if (path.length < 3) return false
    else {
      for i <- 0 to path.length - 1 {
        val temp = path
        temp.remove(i)
        if (temp.contains(i)) return true
        }
      return false
    }
  }
```

If the walker visits a coordinate more than once in a single journey. However, if the walker travels from `(0,0)` to `(0,1)` or even to `(0,2)`, but then returns the same path via `(0,1)` then it should not be seen as a loop.

Can anyone provide a solution for my `isLoop` method?

Comment: Your definition of loop isn't clear - if I understood it correctly, a path has a loop if and only if it contains the the same _vertex_ (e.g. `(0,0)`) more then once, but there is more than one path (composed of _edges_ (e.g. `(0,0) -> (0,1)`) through this vertex?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are just looking to determine if a collection has the same value 2 or more times.

```
@annotation.tailrec
def hasLoop(path: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Boolean =
  if (path.size < 2) false
  else if (path.tail.contains(path.head)) true
  else hasLoop(path.tail)

println(hasLoop(Array((0, 0), (0, 1))))
println(hasLoop(Array((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1))))
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, method should return false for a path like `Array((0,0), (1,0), (0,0))` (that just "returns the same way it went"), for which your solution returns true.

Comment: Pretty sure this will be ~O(n^2) complexity in time since you do O(n) `contains` for each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the most elegant solution, but I think it does what you need:

```
// some type aliases to make this more readable, can do without them too
type Vertex = (Int,Int)
type Edge = (Vertex, Vertex)

def hasLoop(path: Array[Vertex]): Boolean = {
  // create all edges - connections between one vertex and the next one in path
  val edges: Array[Edge] = path.zip(path.drop(1))

  // fold right searching for PREVIOUS edges for which SRC equals current edge's DESTINATION,
  // but DESTINATION does not equal current edge's SOURCE
  val foldResult: (Seq[Edge], Boolean) = edges.foldLeft((Seq[Edge](), false)) {
    case ((visited, found), e) => 
      (visited :+ e, found || visited.exists(oldE => oldE._1 == e._2 && oldE._2 != e._1) )
  }

  foldResult._2 // return the boolean result
}

println(hasLoop(Array((0,0), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,0), (0,1)))) // true
println(hasLoop(Array((0,0), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,0)))) // true
println(hasLoop(Array((0,0), (1,0), (1,-1), (1,0), (0,0)))) // false
println(hasLoop(Array((0,0), (1,0), (1,-1)))) // false
```